# How to detect that music play in background

Tags: android, operating-system, background-music

I want help in detecting if there is a music play in background on the phone or not because I play more than one music sequentially in my app but they are intersection 
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

> AudioManager.isMusicActive()

You can find more detailed info about [AudioManager here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive%28%29)